# Webdriver find_element_by_id works in shell, but won't execute in python script?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver

I am learning python by trying to solve problems.

When I attempt to access an element after logging in to the site, the same command works in shell and doesn't work if its in the following file.

Plus I think my approach is wrong as the element keeps changing its id and the only constant is the "More Search Results" for which I have tried: `find_link_by_text` which fails, I assume because the element doesn't contain an `href`. `find_link_by_xpath` with `contains` text.

Webscraping:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import requests, bs4, re, csv

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\-----\Desktop\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://dir.indiamart.com/search.mp?    ss=Power+Distribution+Transformers")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(10)  #setting a gap for website load

action = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
elm = driver.find_element_by_id("user_sign_in").click()
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id('email')
inputElement.send_keys('xxxxxx')
driver.find_element_by_name("Submit3").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(30)

#The code till above this is working perfectly
# element: 
#<div id="scroll2" class="fm2 p8 cur m_bt2" 
#onclick="javascript:displayResultsLogin('scroll2')"> Show More Results
# </div>
try:
    driver.find_element_by_id("scroll2").click()   
#Trying the the above find_element_* works if I input it in shell.
except:
    print("Didn't work")
    pass
# If I leave it in the file, removing the except, it shows element not found

r = driver.page_source
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
blocks = soup.find_all('div', class_='lst')

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for b in blocks:
        name = b.find(class_='cnm').get_text(strip=True)
        addr = b.find(class_='clg').get_text(strip=True)
        call = b.find(class_='ls_co phn').find(text=re.compile('\d+')).strip()
        writer.writerow([name, addr, call])
```

The last part for some reason when in this file, will only add the 0 from the element into the file and not the xxxxxxxx number.

Comment: Be more clear and concise: you should specify short description of what you're trying to do, expected and actual output, leave just those lines of code that cause the issue + add exception log if there is one... For now it's unclear what you're asking about

Comment: I did post a more to the point question but it seemed more details were required. I will edit this one.

Answer (score 0):

It works in the shell and does not when you run it in a script - this suggests it is a *timing issue*. In the shell, you have delays between each of the commands allowing the page to load, in the script you don't. The problem can be solved with [`WebDriverWait` and one of the Expected Conditions](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits):

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "scroll2"))).click()

# or try locating the element by text
# wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(., 'Show More Results')]"))).click()

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".lst")))

r = driver.page_source
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: Thanks. The first option works even after I get the following error: _raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:_. But I still can't get the `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(., 'Show More Results')]"))).click()` to work. I tried using some other options from the Expected Conditions documentation but still nothing.  The `r = driver.page_source` still doesn't take the number after 0 into consideration. Which it does when I run it without being a part of this script.

Comment: I tried: `try:
    DriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="scroll2" and text() != ""]')))
except:
    raise Exception('Unable to find text in this element after waiting 10 seconds')` using a previous answer by you to check whether the text exists and I get `Unable to find text exception`. Trying to figure out what exactly is "Show More Results" in the element now. :)

Comment: Thanks. A slight change in the commented out section of your code worked when executed once: `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), ' Show More Results')]"))).click()` I am having a tough time understanding why it won't execute again(I used the shell) tried it standalone and using a `for` loop. Gives a _timeout exception_, even though I can see the button is displayed on the page and the text remains the same.